# Calling second Metal kernel in a render frame is slow

Tags: c++, macos, metal

I have an animation which calls Metal kernels to calculate some data for me.

If I call just one simple kernel the avg. time of the kernel call is 4ms. But when I call the second kernel after the first one (a very similar, simple kernel) the 2nd kernel call is 40ms or more... Is it something fundamentally wrong with my code?

I set up the device, queue, library once before animation starts. I also create pipeline state for each kernel in front.

```
// globals created once in the beginning
id<MTLDevice> device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice();
id<MTLCommandQueue> queue = [device newCommandQueueWithMaxCommandBufferCount:1];

MTLCompileOptions *options = [MTLCompileOptions new];
options.fastMathEnabled = YES;
id<MTLLibrary> metal_library = [device newLibraryWithSource:@(MetalKernel_code) options:options error:&err]
[options release];

id<MTLFunction> kernel1 = [[metal_library newFunctionWithName:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:@"kernel1"]/* constantValues : constantValues */] autorelease]);

id<MTLComputePipelineState> pipeline_state_1 = [device newComputePipelineStateWithFunction:kernel1 error:&err];

id<MTLFunction> kernel2 = [[metal_library newFunctionWithName:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:@"kernel2"]/* constantValues : constantValues */] autorelease];
id<MTLComputePipelineState> pipeline_state_2 = [device newComputePipelineStateWithFunction:kernel2 error:&err];
```

And now every frame I call the kernels like this:

```
// invoking first kernel:

id<MTLBuffer> srcDeviceBuf = reinterpret_cast<id<MTLBuffer> >(const_cast<float *>(src));
id<MTLBuffer> dstDeviceBuf = reinterpret_cast<id<MTLBuffer> >(dst);

Kernel1Params params{w, h};
id<MTLBuffer> paramBuf = [[device newBufferWithBytes:&params length:sizeof(Kernel1Params) options:MTLResourceStorageModeManaged]
    autorelease];

id<MTLCommandBuffer> commandBuffer = [queue commandBuffer];
commandBuffer.label = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"kernel1"];

id<MTLComputeCommandEncoder> computeEncoder = [commandBuffer computeCommandEncoder];
[computeEncoder setComputePipelineState:pipeline_state_1];

auto exeWidth = [pipeline_state_1 threadExecutionWidth];
MTLSize threadGroupCount = MTLSizeMake(exeWidth, 1, 1);
MTLSize threadGroups = MTLSizeMake((w + exeWidth - 1) / exeWidth, static_cast<uint32_t>(h), 1);

[computeEncoder setBuffer:srcDeviceBuf offset:0 atIndex:0];
[computeEncoder setBuffer:dstDeviceBuf offset:0 atIndex:1];
[computeEncoder setBuffer:paramBuf offset:0 atIndex:2];

[computeEncoder dispatchThreadgroups:threadGroups threadsPerThreadgroup:threadGroupCount];
[computeEncoder endEncoding];
[commandBuffer commit];
[commandBuffer waitUntilCompleted];


// invoking second kernel

Kernel2Params params{w_small, h_small, w_big, h_big};
id<MTLBuffer> srcDeviceBuf = reinterpret_cast<id<MTLBuffer> >(const_cast<float *>(src));
id<MTLBuffer> dstDeviceBuf = reinterpret_cast<id<MTLBuffer> >(const_cast<float *>(dst));
id<MTLBuffer> paramBuf = [[device newBufferWithBytes:&params length:sizeof(Kernel2Params) options:MTLResourceStorageModeManaged] autorelease];

id<MTLCommandBuffer> commandBuffer = [queue commandBuffer];
commandBuffer.label = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Kernel2"];

id<MTLComputeCommandEncoder> computeEncoder = [commandBuffer computeCommandEncoder];
[computeEncoder setComputePipelineState:pipeline_state_2];

auto exeWidth = [pipeline_state_2 threadExecutionWidth];
MTLSize threadGroupCount = MTLSizeMake(exeWidth, 1, 1);
MTLSize threadGroups = MTLSizeMake((w_small + exeWidth - 1) / exeWidth, static_cast<uint32_t>(h_small), 1);

[computeEncoder setBuffer:srcDeviceBuf offset:0 atIndex:0];
[computeEncoder setBuffer:dstDeviceBuf offset:0 atIndex:1];
[computeEncoder setBuffer:paramBuf offset:0 atIndex:2];

[computeEncoder dispatchThreadgroups:threadGroups threadsPerThreadgroup:threadGroupCount];
[computeEncoder endEncoding];
[commandBuffer commit];
[commandBuffer waitUntilCompleted];

// copy from GPU to CPU
NSData *outdata = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:[dstDeviceBuf contents] length:(size_t) (w_small * h_small * 3) freeWhenDone:false];

[outdata getBytes:dst length:(size_t) (w_small * h_small * 3)];
```

Both kernels can be as simple as copying the input buffer to the output buffer (1) and simple image resize (2):

```
// kernel 1
kernel void Kernel1( device float const* src, device float* dst, device Kernel1Params *inValues, uint2 inXY [[ thread_position_in_grid ]])
{
    if ((inXY.x >= w) || (inXY.y >= h)) {
        return;
    }
    const int index = ((inXY.y * inValues->w) + inXY.x) * 4;

    dst[index + 0] = src[index + 0];
    dst[index + 1] = src[index + 1];
    dst[index + 2] = src[index + 2];
    dst[index + 3] = src[index + 3];
}

// kernel 2
kernel void Kernel2( device float const* src, device unsigned char* dst, device Kernel2Params *inValues, uint2 inXY [[ thread_position_in_grid ]])
{
    if ((inXY.x >= w_small) || (inXY.y >= h_small)) {
        return;
    }
    const int index = ((inXY.y * inValues->w_small) + inXY.x) * 3;
    int index2;

    if(inValues->w_small == inValues->w_big && inValues->h_small == inValues->h_big) {
        index2 = ((inXY.y * inValues->w_big) + inXY.x) * 4;
    } else {
        const unsigned int x_big = (int)((float)(inXY.x * inValues->w_big) / (float)inValues->w_small);
        const unsigned int y_big = inValues->h_big - (int)((float)(inXY.y * inValues->h_big) / (float)inValues->h_small) - 1;

        index2 = (y_big * inValues->w_big + x_big) * 4;
    }

    dst[index + 0] = (unsigned char)(src[index2 + 2] * 255.0f);
    dst[index + 1] = (unsigned char)(src[index2 + 1] * 255.0f);
    dst[index + 2] = (unsigned char)(src[index2 + 0] * 255.0f);
}
```

Comment: Uh, what's with the bizarre `reinterpret_cast`s? Are you running with validation enabled? Also, is there a reason you're waiting for the command buffer to complete after dispatching each compute shader?

Comment: I tried without the call to "waitUntilCompleted" but nothing changed. First kernel takes 1-4ms and the second 40-60ms...

Comment: You don't need 'waitUntilCompleted' and 'commit' after first kernel, it's enough call commit and wait once only after encoding both kernels.